# Do external resources slow down a page more than internal resources?

Tags: download, external, html

I have limited bandwidth with my web hosting company as I picked the cheapest plan.

Is having images hosted on a website like www.imgur.com in your website slower than having them on the same server as your website's files?

eg.

`<img src="photo.png" alt="Image hosted on same server">`

`<img src="http://i.imgur.com/2kQirjx.png" alt="Image hosted on imgur">`

Comment: That's like asking if your own car is faster than a rental car. It depends on how fast your server is and how fast the external server is, and the location of the servers and the user, among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the performance of your server and the other. The request to get the image is made by the browser during the DOM's loading, then a HTTP connection is established and the transfer speed depends on the performance of the server, in fact. Banally, if you have a limited bandwidth and the alternative is to get the resource from a C.D.N., the second one is definitely the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Not always, but it sometimes (often?) is. Additionally, the external server may be down - your users will not receive the external resources until that server is up again.

Imgur is a high traffic service, so outages may be not-so-infrequent there.